# afterTextChanged append not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
text.addOnTextChanged(new TextWatcher() {

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      if (s.length() == 4 || s.length() == 9 || s.length() == 14) {
          text.append("-");
      }
  }

}
```

For some reason, that code doesn't work. I simplified it to the core of what it should be. Ideally, you'd see "1234-5678-1234-5678" as an output, because I take 16 digits max. I got it to work with `text.setText(s.toString() + "-")` and then in a post runnable, set the selection to `s.length() + 1`, but append takes care of that for you. Further, for a few milliseconds you can tell that the cursor goes back to the beginning due to `setText` before `setSelection` goes into effect.

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 7):

your input type in your xml edittext declaration should not be "number". Swap out inputType with digit like this:

```
android:digits="0123456789 -."
```

Comment: just changing the input type to "phone" should do the work

Answer (score 1):

try this code.Working fine

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

            if (arg2 == 0) {
                if (arg0.length() == 4 || arg0.length() == 9
                        || arg0.length() == 14) {
                    editText.append("-");

                }
            } else {
                if (arg0.length() == 4 || arg0.length() == 9
                        || arg0.length() == 14) {
                    editText.append("");

                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text.addOnTextChanged(new TextWatcher() {

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      if (s.length() == 4 || s.length() == 9 || s.length() == 14) {
          s.append("-");
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Don't use this method. It would seem to work fine at first glance. But, when you try deleting (backspace), the `afterTextChanged` would be called again and it would revert the changes made by delete

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun setNumberChangeListener(){
    var actionDelete = false
    cardNumber.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            actionDelete = after == 0
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            s?.let {
                when (it.length) {
                    4, 9, 14 -> {
                        if (!actionDelete)
                            it.append(" ")
                        else
                            it.delete(s.lastIndex, s.lastIndex+1.coerceAtMost(s.lastIndex))
                    }
                    else -> {}
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```